# Javascript error missing name after . operator on variable function

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I need to fix this javascript error I am having "missing name after . operator on variable". This is my current code I am trying to get working.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="myFunction()">

<select>
    <option>1</option>
</select>
<br/>
<select>
    <option>1</option>
</select>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
    if(typeof document.body.ontouchstart == "undefined"){actionIn = "onmouseover"; actionOut = "onmouseout"}
    else{actionIn = "ontouchstart"; actionOut = "ontouchend";}

    var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("SELECT");
    for (var i = 0;i < elem.length; i++){
        elem[i].[actionIn] = function(){this.style.background='red';}
        elem[i].[actionOut] = function(){this.style.background='';}
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ermmmmm what is this `elem[i].[actionIn]`

Comment: I already answered this in a comment on your previous question.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use *either* [dot](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Dot_notation) or [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation), not both:

```
elem[i][actionIn] = function(){this.style.background='red';}
elem[i][actionOut] = function(){this.style.background='';}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a `.` between the two square bracket pairs.

`elem[i][actionIn]` and `elem[i][actionOut]`

should suffice.