# How to get an array inside an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Hi I have trouble with an array response of json.
I'm supposed to get the members of the objects. but that array is inside another array.
This is the array that is being returned.

```
var arr = [
[
    {
        "id": 4243430853,
        "email": "jayduco2@gmail.com",
    },
    {
        "id": 4227666181,
        "email": "deofederickduran@gmail.com",

    },
    {
        "id": 4227644293,
        "email": "kfsucayan@gmail.com",

    }
],
[
    {
        "id": 4243430854,
        "email": "jayduco2@gmail.com",
    },
    {
        "id": 4227666182,
        "email": "deofederickduran@gmail.com",

    },
    {
        "id": 4227644294,
        "email": "kfsucayan@gmail.com",

    }
]   
];
```

How can i dig down to the values? before I would use `arr[i].email`, but now it doesn't work. I've tried arr[0].[i].email, but returns be the error `missing name after . operator`. Is there a way that I can remove that outer array?

Comment: Just remove the `.` between the brackets.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript error missing name after . operator on variable function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16172526/javascript-error-missing-name-after-operator-on-variable-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `arr[i][j].email`. `i` to loop over the array `arr` itself and `j` to loop over each sub-array.

`arr[i]` will give you something like this (if `i == 0` for example):

```
[
    {
        "id": 4243430853,
        "email": "jayduco2@gmail.com",
    },
    {
        "id": 4227666181,
        "email": "deofederickduran@gmail.com",
    },
    {
        "id": 4227644293,
        "email": "kfsucayan@gmail.com",
    }
]
```

and then `arr[i][j]` will give something like this (if `i == 0` and `j == 2`):

```
{
    "id": 4227644293,
    "email": "kfsucayan@gmail.com",
}
```

then you can access the `email` property using `arr[i][j].email`.

Comment: Thanks that's so silly of me to forget that very simple array method

Answer (score 0):

There's two ways to access objects in Javascript: using periods or using square brackets. Here, you're trying to mix the two, which works, but probably isn't the best practice. You should pick whichever is best for the situation. Here, you'd want to use the brackets:

```
arr[i][j]["email"];
```

Note that when using variables, you will always need to use brackets as opposed to periods.